# Load Google Map through JQuery Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

Where in the flow of execution does the `initialize()` function need to appear in the code to allow a Google Map v3 API map to be loaded through a JQuery `.load()` call.

The code I have at the moment looks like this

```
$('#maplink').click(function(){
    $('.fades').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#googleMap').show();
    $('#googleMap').load("map.html");
    initialize();
});`
```

However, this isn't initializing the map after the AJAX call.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but for anyone who ends up here, loading a .html page into a `div` is not the right way to dynamically load a Maps API map. Here's how it should be done:

First, put all of your Maps API script in the host page - the page that has the `#googleMap` div. Or, if you want that script itself in a file that you load asynchronously, put it in a .js file and load it with `$.getScript()`.

Then, if you want to load both the Maps API and the map asynchronously in response to your button click, use the code from [this asynchronous Maps API example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async).

In that example page, you won't be using this line:

```
window.onload = loadScript;
```

Instead, you'll call the `loadScript()` function from your click handler:

```
$('#maplink').click(function(){
    $('.fades').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#googleMap').show();
    loadScript();
});
```

where `loadScript()` is the Maps API loading function from the example.

In fact, you could use `$.getScript()` to load the Maps API - just give it the URL used in the `loadScript()` sample function. That `loadScript()` function is pretty much equivalent to `$.getScript()` except for the hard coded URL.

You'll also need to change things in the `initialize()` function in that example to match your page, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with jQuery, but I'm not really sure why you want jQuery to load the map. If you are trying to make the map load asynchronously google provides a way https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API Other than that. I can't be much help. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The initialize() call to google maps can be added as a script inside map.html and then when jquery includes the html it will execute the javascript.

Alternatively, you could do the following

```
$('#googleMap').load("map.html",function(){
    alert('map is loaded and ready');
});
```

The issue that you are having is that the load call is asynchronous and therefore, when initialize() is called your ajax load probably has not completed.